# PHP Class Variable problem

Tags: php, html, class

I have this class:

```
class TestClass
{
    var $testvar;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$testvar = "Hullo";
        echo($this->$testvar);
    }
}
```

And this method for accessing:

```
function getCurrent()
{
    $gen = new TestClass();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: testvar in /Users/myuser/Sites/codebase/functions.php on line 28
>   Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /Users/myuser/Sites/codebase/functions.php on line 28

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the $ before testvar in your call to it:

```
$this->testvar = "Hullo";
echo($this->testvar);
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use the variable reference when you access the variable:

```
$this->testvar;
```

By using `$this->$testvar`, your PHP script will first look for `$testvar`, then find a variable in your class by that name.  i.e.

```
$testvar = 'myvar';
$this->$testvar == $this->myvar;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since *var* is deprecated I'd suggest to declare it as one of private, public or protected.

```
class TestClass
{
    protected $testvar;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->testvar = "Hullo";
        echo $this->testvar;
    }
}
```