# How to get variable in class?

Tags: php

> **UPDATE**

**OTHER CLASS**

- OtherClass->functionA
- OtherClass->functionB
- OtherClass->whatever (dynamic) <-- Possible to call OtherClass->foo or OtherClass->bar

**CLASS A**

```
class A
{
    protected $_data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $other = new OtherClass;
        $something = $this->_data;
        $this->process = $other->$something; // Not Work
    }

    public function ipsum()
    {
        return $this->process; 
    }
}
```

**CLASS B**

```
class B extends A
{
    protected $_data = 'string';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function lorem()
    {
        return $this->ipsum(); // $other->string; 
    }
}
```

How can i get `$_data`?

It working with `$other->foo` without variable

Help.. Thanks

Comment: `$process = $other->something;`

Comment: Could you show the content of B::__construct?

Comment: Upps sorry.. I have no B class. Edited

Comment: Then parent::__construct() does nothing, and so $this->_data is left as null since it was defined with no default value. If $this->_data is never set, then $something is null, and $other->$something does nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Class Variable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663684/php-class-variable-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean:

```
$process = $other->something;
```

`$other->$something` will return the property whose name is stored in `$something` from the object `$other`, and, from your example above, `$something` is `NULL`.

Comment: I have OtherClass. OtherClass->functionA and have OtherClass->whatever (dynamic). `$something` get value from `$this->_data` and i want to call OtherClass->whateverA or OtherClass->whateverB via `$this->_data`